# Separate a column with uneven/unequal strings and with no delimiters

Tags: r, tidyr

How would I separate a column like this where the data has delimiters but the rest does not and it has some unequal strings?

Input:
                 id

> 142    TM500A2013PISA8/22/17BG
>   143    TM500CAGE2012QUDO8/22/1720+

Output:

> category  site garden plot  year  species   date    portion
>   142        TM   500    A    2013   PISA   8/22/17     BG
>   143        TM   500   CAGE  2012   QUDO   8/22/17    20+

I poked around other questions and tried something that may work if it was an equal string ie:

```
>df <- avgmass %>% separate(id, c("site", "garden", "plot", "year", 
    "species", "sampledate", "portion"),sep=cumsum(c(2,3,3,4,4,5)))
```

But as the plot id is either A, B or CAGE; the date has "/" - I am not sure how to approach it.

As I am relatively new to R, I tried searching for more details on how to use the sep argument but to no avail... Thank you for your help.

Comment: if it is not of fixed length, try with `?extract`

Comment: Could you show the expected output

Comment: We have no idea what those letters and numbers mean. What are the rules for splitting fields? Why in the world is the data formatted like this?

Comment: I added the expected output, sry about that! The data was originally like the output data, but I united the columns together in order to run the aggregate function so I could find an average of some values that correspond to each row and also preserve all the information.

Comment: You can aggregate by multiple columns - next time post a question to ask how to do that correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below may work for you, assuming that the "site", "garden" and "species" columns are of a fixed width.

```
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(site = substr(id, 1, 2),
             garden = substr(id, 3, 5),
             plot = ifelse(substr(id, 6, 9) == "CAGE", substr(id, 6, 9), substr(id, 6, 6)),
             year = ifelse(substr(id, 6, 9) == "CAGE", substr(id, 10, 13), substr(id, 7, 10)),
             species = ifelse(substr(id, 6, 9) == "CAGE", substr(id, 14, 17), substr(id, 11, 14)),
             sampledate = ifelse(substr(id, 6, 9) == "CAGE", substr(id, 18, nchar(id)), substr(id, 15, nchar(id)))) %>%
             separate(sampledate, into = c("m","d","y"), sep = "/") %>%
             mutate(portion = substr(y, 3, nchar(y)),
                    sampledate = as.Date(paste(m, d, substr(y, 1, 2), sep = "-"), format = "%m-%d-%y"),
                    m = NULL,
                    d = NULL,
                    y = NULL)
```

Comment: If you are creating the "id" column yourself though, it would probably be better to include a delimiter between the fields, and use that to separate out the columns again later.

Comment: Thank you! I did try to run this and it had issues inputting a portion after the date, but I took your advice and added a separator when I united my columns and then used the separate function. It worked beautifully!